# Ruby on Rails - Delayed job sleep delay less than 5 secs

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, delayed-job

How effective is setting the sleep delay of delayed job less than 5 secs in ruby on rails. 
What will be the adverse effect due to this change ? 
What will be the overall impact on application ?

Comment: Delaying a job usually means that it's not time-critical. Maybe you should take a look into Sidekiq.

Answer (score 2):

`Delayed::Worker.sleep_delay` configure the amount of time in seconds for which a worker will sleep before checking for new jobs again when there were no jobs found in the queue.

Checking for new jobs always means DelayedJob runs a database query.

When you know that there are hardly any jobs in your system then you can set the `sleep_delay` to a higher number to reduce the number of queries against your database and to reduce CPU and IO usage of your servers.

When you have jobs which should run in almost real-time and you can not or do not want the wait a few seconds for each of them, then you can set the `sleep_delay` to a smaller number. That means DelayedJob will pick up new jobs faster.

What does that mean to your application? Will a small number impact the performance of your application? That depends on your application:

- The rate of web-requests against the number of background jobs.
- The CPU and IO of your servers and what the jobs do.
- Multiple servers or just one? Dedicated servers of DelayedJob and DB?
- The number of DelayJob workers.

I suggest playing around with the numbers a bit and find a balance between the average time you want to wait for jobs to be picked up and the base-load of your servers. Do you need to check for new jobs every second?

And for most applications, unless they have a lot of traffic and high number of background jobs, I would not expect the changing this value would have any effect to the rest of the application at all.